Am I correctly measuring my toilet rough-in distance?
I have removed an old toilet in a bathroom that we never use to refresh it and install a new one. I was surprised to see that the installation bolts on the flange are only 9in from the wall. I have not found toilets on the market with this short rough in. Am I measuring it wrong? The other two toilets I replaced in this house were regular 12in and I had no problem whatsoever. I was tempted to just buy a 10in rough-in toilet and see how it goes but I thought I'd ask first.
Note: I put my tape measure against the base molding but that is just a very thin 1/8in vinyl material. It does not add anything even close to an inch to the wall.
The wall is also very vertical, with no real imperfection that could account for the extra thickness.

I have pulled the flange that was too full of wax and a little crooked.

The center of the pipe is just shy of 9in from the wall. Would a 10in rough-in toilet work here?

Individual variation makes it more of a "could" than a "would."
I have a particular example of a 12" nominal rough-in toilet that sits far enough from the wall that it could be used for a 10" - but another example of the "same" toilet might not, as the dimensions are explicitly stated to have potential variation from nominal. But I can slide a 2" object between that toilet and the wall without binding anywhere.
It would appear (can't really say without being there when it was installed) that someone (probably) had a 10" that would allow for this 9" installation, measured it for actual rather than nominal, and located the flange to suit. So you'd need to assemble and measure 10" (nominal) toilets hoping to find one that will fit 9" actual, as far as I know (I've never seen a 9" nominal, either.)
Whether you could make an offset flange work here (or how difficult it would be...) to get 10" actual I can't tell for sure.

Thanks. Yeah I understand. I ordered a 10in rough-in toilet and I'll see how it goes. In case it does not fit, my first plan would be to check what I can do with the wall behind, it might be easier than messing with the cast iron in the concrete slab. I am appalled by how bad jobs were done back in the day ('70s in this case). This seems to me like a textbook case of "f. the next guy"

Don't be appalled. Much more was done by hand and eye "back in the day" with much less accommodating products. You'd probably be amazed at the actual craftsmanship required.

The point is that this bathroom is the biggest we have in the house and in particular, there is a lot of unused space in front of the toilet. Yet, it's the only one that uses less than a 12" rough-in. Back in the day they did not have laser levels and many of the battery operated tools that we take for granted, but this was just badly planned and put together in a rush.
